# insertar value date en informix desde php usando pdo

Tags: php, pdo

Tengo un problema cuando trato de hacer un insert de tipo date a mi base de datos en informix desde php usando pdo.
No tengo problemas con otro tipo de datos, hice la prueba con la mayoría 
Por ejemplo para hacer un insert a esta tabla

```
Create prueba1 (
cod serial,
id int,
nombre varchar(30),
fecha datetime
)
```

Desde PHP ( hay 2 maneras)(primero defino mi conexion)

```
$cona = new PDO("informix:host=10....; service=9040;database=sap2000; server=central1; protocol=onsoctcp;EnableScrollableCursors=1;CLIENT_LOCALE=en_US.CP1252;DB_LOCALE=en_US.819", "xxxxxx", "xxxxxx");
$dato1 = "(0)";
$dato2 = 333;
$dato3 = "ddddaaaannn";
$dato4 = "2016-10-19 09:10:00"

//Manera 1
    $sql1 = $cona->prepare("insert into prueba1 values ($dato1, $dato2, '".$dato3."', '".$dato4."')");
    $sql1->execute();

//Manera 2
    $sql2 = ("insert into prueba1 values ($dato1, $dato2, '".$dato3."', '".$dato4."')");
$result = $cona->query($sql2);
```

Con cualquiera de estas dos formas no tengo problemas con el insert.

Para hacer la prueba igual funciona desde el gestor de mi base de datos informix.
    insert into prueba1 values ((0),73, 'F000', '2016-10-19 08:10:00')

El problema es cuando intento hacer el insert de un tipo de dato date

por ejemplo si tengo una tabla asi

```
create table prueba2
(
fecha date
)
```

haciendo directo desde  mi gestor no tengo problema, es decir

```
insert into prueba2 values ('2016-10-30')
```

El problema esta cuando hago lo mismo desde php

Desde PHP ( hay 2 maneras)(primero defino mi conexion)

```
 $cona = new PDO("informix:host=10....; service=9040;database=sap2000; server=central1; protocol=onsoctcp;EnableScrollableCursors=1;CLIENT_LOCALE=en_US.CP1252;DB_LOCALE=en_US.819", "xxxxxx", "xxxxxx");
    $dato1 = "2016-10-30";

    //Manera 1
        $sql1 = $cona->prepare("insert into prueba2 values ('".$dato1."')");
        $sql1->execute();

    //Manera 2
        $sql2 =("insert into prueba2 values ('".$dato1."')");
    $result = $cona->query($sql2);
```

Que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?
Tambien intenté dandole formato de fecha a mi variable pero sin ningun resultado

Comment: Añadir que utilizo un try y catch pero no me manda ninguna excepcion ni nada

Comment: en la base de datos como tienes el campo `Tipo` configurado? `DATE` o `DATETIME`.. y otra cosa... usa sentencias preparadas

Comment: Tengo declarado el campo como tipo DATE

Comment: Fijate que te faltan poner comillas, **... values ('$dato1')**. Ese tipo de errores se solucionan, como bien dice @aldanux, usando sentencias preparadas.

Comment: yo me equivoqué al escribir el ejemplo pero en mi código original tengo las comillas

Comment: Ya corregí el error, mil disculpas

Comment: si solo tengo 1 campo (fecha) tipo date en mi tabla prueba2.   El problema es que estas tablas solo son de prueba ya que la base que utilizo ya tiene sus campos definidos, y no puedo cambiarla.

Comment: toda la parte del php está bien y debería funcionar sin problemas...

Comment: será algún bug de pdo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si es que a alguien le sirve ya pude resolver este tema con la siguiente solución:

```
$dato1 = "2016/10/30";
    $sql1 = $cona->prepare("update prueba SET  prueba2= TO_DATE('".$dato1."', \"%Y/%m/%d\")");
    $sql1->execute();
```

Tuve que darle ese formato dentro de la consulta. 
Algo importante es que como ven `$dato1 = 2016/10/30`  y el formato tiene que ser el mismo cuando se lo define en la consulta, si es que `$dato1 = "2016-10-30"`  es decir - en vez de / en el formato habria que cambiar igual.

Answer (score 0):

Has probado así?

```
$sql1 = $cona->prepare("insert into prueba2 values (?)");
$sql1->execute(array($dato1));
```

O de esta forma

```
$sql1= $cona->prepare("insert into prueba2 values (:dato1)");
$sql1->bindParam(':dato1', $dato1);
$sql1->execute();
```

Comment: Hola Raul, probé de la manera que me indicas pero sin efectos.